# How to write a MySQL query that returns a temporary column containing flags for whether or not an item related to that row exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

How might I write a MySQL query to achieve the desired result shown below?

I have two tables:

```
TABLE_USERS:

 ID | Name  |  ... 
--------------------
 1  | Ash   |
 2  | Tim   |
 3  | Jim   |
 4  | Jay   |
 5  | Tom   |


TABLE_FLAGS:

 ID | Reason |  ...
----------------------
 2  |  ??    |
 4  |  ...   |
```

I want to know how to write a query that yields a result with the following columns:

```
DESIRED RESULT:


 ID | Name  | Flagged
----------------------
 1  | Ash   |  false
 2  | Tim   |  true
 3  | Jim   |  false
 4  | Jay   |  true
 5  | Tom   |  false
```

I could do:

```
SELECT TABLE_USERS.ID, TABLE_USERS.NAME
FROM TABLE_USER
```

To get the first two columns, but I'm not sure how to get the last one...

The final column does not directly correspond to a column in one of the two tables; instead for each row it returns true or false base on whether an entry for that rows id value exists in TABLE_FLAGS

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   SELECT   tu.ID, 
            tu.NAME,
            CASE WHEN tf.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Flagged
      FROM  TABLE_USER tu
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_FLAGS tf ON tu.ID = tf.ID
```

Comment: was going to suggest the same except using if(tf.id IS NOT NULL, 'true', 'false') as flagged. Nice answer!

Comment: I'll get an `Error Code: 1054` for a `Flagged = ...` construct.

Answer (score 1):

This will show your desired output:

```
SELECT tu.ID, tu.NAME,
       CASE WHEN tf.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Flagged
  FROM TABLE_USER tu
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_FLAGS tf ON tu.ID = tf.ID ;
```