# Select column based on whether a specific row in another table exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Question is similar to this one [How to write a MySQL query that returns a temporary column containing flags for whether or not an item related to that row exists in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134558/how-to-write-a-mysql-query-that-returns-a-temporary-column-containing-flags-for)

Except that I need to be more specific about which rows exists

I have two tables: 'competitions' and 'competition_entries'

Competitions:

```
ID    | NAME      | TYPE
--------------------------------
1     | Example   | example type
2     | Another   | example type
```

Competition Entries

```
ID    | USERID    | COMPETITIONID
---------------------------------
1     | 100       | 1
2     | 110       | 1
3     | 110       | 2
4     | 120       | 1
```

I want to select the competitions but add an additional column which specifies whether the user has entered the competition or not. This is my current SELECT statement

```
SELECT
    c.[ID],
    c.[NAME],
    c.[TYPE],
    (CASE 
        WHEN e.ID IS NOT NULL AND e.USERID = @userid THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS 'ENTERED'      

FROM competitions AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN competition_entries AS e
ON e.COMPETITIONID = c.ID
```

My desired result set from setting the `@userid` parameter to `110` is this

```
ID    | NAME    | TYPE         | ENTERED
-------------------------------------
1     | Example | example type | 1
2     | Another | example type | 1
```

But instead I get this

```
ID    | NAME    | TYPE         | ENTERED
-------------------------------------
1     | Example | example type | 0
1     | Example | example type | 1
1     | Example | example type | 0
2     | Another | example type | 1
```

Because it's counting the entries for all user ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing your query

```
SELECT
    c.[ID],
    c.[NAME],
    c.[TYPE],
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN e.ID IS NOT NULL AND e.USERID = @userid THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS 'ENTERED'      
FROM competitions AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN competition_entries AS e ON e.COMPETITIONID = c.ID
GROUP BY
    c.[ID],
    c.[NAME],
    c.[TYPE]
```

An alternative is to rewrite it using EXISTS which is pretty much the same but may be easier to understand.
BTW, using single quotes on the column name is deprecated. Use square brackets.

```
SELECT
    c.[ID],
    c.[NAME],
    c.[TYPE],
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM competition_entries AS e
        WHERE e.COMPETITIONID = c.ID
          AND e.USERID = @userid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [ENTERED]
FROM competitions AS c
```

Comment: Yup that works using the second one and much easier to understand, I knew it was something along those lines. Thanks for the naming tip too.