# How do I include a column in a query that shows if item exists in another table?

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I'm having what I hope is a momentary lapse of reasoning.  I have the following schema:

[image: schema]

```
SELECT RoleName FROM aspnet_Roles; gives:
-----------------------------------------
Administrator
Backend
Business Manager
Content Editor
Employee
Salesperson

SELECT RoleName FROM aspnet_Roles r INNER JOIN admin_page_role apr ON r.RoleId = apr.RoleId WHERE apr.PageId = 4;
------------------------------------------
Administrator
Business Manager
Salesperson
```

What I want is the full list of the first query along with whether or not the role is assigned, like:

```
| RoleName        |  IsAssignedToPage
---------------------------------------
Administrator             1
Backend                   0
Business Manager          1
Content Editor            0
Employee                  0
Salesperson               1
```

I looked at [How to write a MySQL query that returns a temporary column containing flags...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134558/how-to-write-a-mysql-query-that-returns-a-temporary-column-containing-flags-for) which makes sense, but my admin_page_role table is a bridge table that can contain many page-role combinations.

Comment: I should have shown the queries I tried.  I will remember to do that next time!  I was very close and it would have saved someone a minute or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT RoleName, case when apr.roleid is null then 0 else 1 end as IsAssignedToPage   
FROM aspnet_Roles r   
LEFT JOIN admin_page_role apr ON r.RoleId = apr.RoleId and apr.PageId = 4
```

Comment: Doh!  "r.RoleId = apr.RoleId and apr.PageId = 4" that was the missing part of my attempts.  Thank you!